# Appending to dynamical created element issue/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

It **seems** that when I create elements using JQuery (dynamicaly), it wont allow me to append again using jquery. I am assuming its due to the inherent qualities of the append() method.

Below is my js code that is trying to append to already dynamicaly created DOM:

```
function displayComments(posts, status){

  $.each(posts, function (index, post) {
   var comments = post.comments;
    var textComment = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){            
    var textComment = comments[i]["author"] + " " + comments[i]["content"] + " " + comments[i]["date"]; 
        }
            var divAdd = ("#commentSection" +post.postId);
           $(divAdd).append(textComment);

});
```

}

I am certain that the divAdd works because I checked on my webpage and it matches and I am sure the textcomment works because I alerted it. So that leaves the .append

Below is my code that creates the elements dynamically:

```
function displayPosts(posts, status) {

$.each(posts, function (index, post) {
    var tags = post.tags;
    var textTags = "";
    ///////////////////// TAGS ////////////////////////////////
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
           textTags = textTags + " #"+ tags[i]["name"];
    }

    ///////////////////// GENERAL ////////////////////////////////    
    $('#parentPostBox').append($('<div class="postBox" id="' + post.postId + '">' 
          + post.content //POST CONTENT
          + '<p class="tags"> '+ textTags //TAGS
          + '</p><div id="#commentSection' + post.postId //COMMENTS
          + '" class="commentStyle"></div><form><input type="text" value="" id="putComment'
          + post.postId +'"></form><button class="commentButton1" id="comment' 
          + post.postId + '" type="button">Add Comment</button>'));//COMMENT BUTTON

});
```

}

[My DOM & webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQRWL.jpg)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently not formatting the id correctly when creating your 'dynamic' elements:

Ids do not need the `#` hashtag when being written as attributes in markup. Selecting ids through the `#` hashtag is a CSS convention (adopted by jQuery too).

Alter the offending line:

```
+ '</p><div id="commentSection' + post.postId //COMMENTS (without #)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm, so silly that I didnt see that